# autoCrat naming google documents

Tags: document

Can autocrat be set up to use a column heading to name the document when it is merged. I have a form that creates student information and final grades in a spreadsheet and I use autocrat to merge data from the spreadsheet to a google doc., but each document merged has the same name unless I change it in the merge process or after the merge is complete. It seems if we could use `<<Student>>` in the "File naming convention to use" in the Set merge type step this would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you just have to use the proper tag at the fifth step of autocrat configuration. It'll probably be something like $student.